# Ubuntu Mate battery icon turned red

Tags: power-management, indicator, battery, mate

I am using Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 on Asus Vivobook M580VD

Recently battery icon changed and become red and empty inside(look at the image)

[image: battery icon]

This happened after I restarted notebook. I didn't restarted it for several months and I think I could have done something to cause this and restarting just applied changes that I accidentally made. But I don't know what could caused this.

When I point cursor to it, it says "Laptop battery waiting to charge (100.0%)"

If I disconnect/connect charger it will show normal battery icon for 2 minutes and then will turn red as in image.
Also it shows normal icon while battery is charging

I tried to uninstall/install mate-power-manager, but it didn't helped.

Also in order to make sure that it is not hardware issue I tried to boot from live USB. On Live USB with Ubuntu MATE 18.04 it shows normal battery icon.

I would like to ask for your help in order to understand why is it showing red icon and how to change it back.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall theme packages - with something like `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mate-icon-theme mate-icon-theme-faenza mate-themes ubuntu-mate-icon-themes`?

Comment: @N0rbert I tried. I run the command. Reinstall went without errors, then I restarted laptop to make sure that changes will be applied, but it didn't helped. The battery icon is still red.